# Why my query returns all fields?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need to find just specific field which calls `dados`, this works perfectly but returns all fields to me. 
How I can do to return just `dados` field?

```
@Query("{\"dados\": {$ne: null}}, {\"dados\": 1}")
List<Contato> findOnlyDados();
```

Entity (without getters and setters)

```
     @Document
     public class Contato {

        @Id
        private String id;
        String nome;
        List<Info> dados;
        @DBRef
        Agencia agencia;

    static class Info {
        String campo;
        String valor;
    }

   }
```

When I make the GET Request

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8181/api/contatos/search/findOnlyDados"
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "contatos": [
      {
        "nome": "Contato one",
        "dados": [
          {
            "campo": "teste um",
            "valor": "fmdsf"
          },
          {
            "campo": "dois",
            "valor": "bdfbfd"
          }
        ],
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8181/api/contatos/55b66de7ccf21a7a1cfcd403"
          },
          "agencia": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8181/api/contatos/55b66de7ccf21a7a1cfcd403/agencia"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nome": "Contato bgf",
        "dados": [
          {
            "campo": "teste jghj",
            "valor": "ytrf"
          },
          {
            "campo": "jhjhn",
            "valor": "bdfbfd"
          }
        ],
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8181/api/contatos/55b66dfeccf21a7a1cfcd404"
          },
          "agencia": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8181/api/contatos/55b66dfeccf21a7a1cfcd404/agencia"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're sending both the query and fields as single String.  Try `@Query(value="{'dados': {$ne: null}}", fields="{'dados' : 1}")`.  Inspired by [spring-data examples](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the fields to be returned by a query use the `fields` attribute of the `@Query` annotation.